# Asp.Net Hosted Blazor + Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I see plenty of documentation/examples for enabling Azure AD with Server-side Blazor apps. Unfortunately there seems to be zero (0) documentation for Asp.net Hosted Blazor Apps.

At the very least, i would like to secure the API's with Azure AD.
But it is also unfortunate that the VS project template for Asp.net Hosted Blazor projects do not allow any Authentication options.

> - Is this an impossibility at this point in time? 
>     Can we expect this to
> - supported in the future (hopefully in the near future)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is definitely documentation for this.

Have you seen these guides?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/client-side?view=aspnetcore-3.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0

There is a recent blog post as well. https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-blazor-to-build-a-client-side-single-page-app-with-net-core/

Are these what you are looking for? Looks like this was only recently added.

Comment: Thanks. Only the 1st link seems relevant to anything deploy related.

Comment: The 1st article seems to be not entirely correct. Specifically in the section about Routing. For instance, I can definitely go to www.mysite.com/About and have the about page rendered.

Comment: No need to publish ads for  chrissainty. Please, read the question once again. The question is about the use of 'Azure AD authentication', not Jwt Bearer authentication.

Comment: @Marilee Turscak - MSFT, with all due respect, may I ask what is in your answer that merits the accepted token. You've provided two links (first ones) that provide no knowledge or information about using  'Azure AD authentication'; the third one is not only out of context and not relevant , but also ancient. Four months in Blazor developing time is huge. Now ask yourself why your answer was accepted ? Is it fair to others, etc. ? Sorry...

Comment: The user accepted the thread because it answered the question, which was whether there was documentation for this. The first link was the best one but the others are potentially useful resources. I didn't force anyone to accept the answer so I'm not sure why you're criticizing me for it. There's nothing unfair to others about it. You're free to provide your own answer if you have a better one.

Comment: Sorry @ Marilee, I apologize for directing my criticism at you. It should have been direted otherwise. However, the user did not accept the answer because "it answered the question." as you suggest. Your answer provides no value  as to how to use  Azure AD authentication with Asp.Net Hosted Blazor. Please read the title of the question.

Comment: He asked whether it was supported and whether there was documentation for it. "Unfortunately there seems to be zero (0) documentation for Asp.net Hosted Blazor Apps."

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor/blazor-azure-ad-adal/). As per my understanding, it is not yet directly supported scenario. Let's hope future releases address this issue.

Meanwhile, if you want to look twitter integration, check this [link](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/06-authentication-and-authorization.md)